# K&R c programming book 3.7 trim function example

Tags: c

I've been following K&R book 2nd version for c programming, but in 3.7 part, here is the screenshot of the function and my code part:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/* trim: removing the trailing blanks, tabs and newlines  */
int trim(char s[]);
int main(){
    char s[] = "hello,world       \t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    int length = trim(s);
    printf("%d\n", length);
    return 0;
}
int trim(char s[]){
   int n;
   for (n = strlen(s) -1 ; n >= 0 ; n--)
       if (s[n] != ' ' && s[n] != '\n' && s[n] != '\t')
            break;
   s[n+1] = '\0';
   return n;
}
```

The following is the output I get from running it:

[image]

Obviously the result length is 11, "hello,world", but the program outputs 10,
the reason is s[n+1] = '\n', instead of s[++n];I think it should be s[++n],
otherwise I will get the wrong output ==> 10, how to deal with it? could anyone plz take a look at it?

Comment: The code in the picture (always a bad idea) and the code in the text (normally a good idea) are not strictly identical. Did you notice?

Comment: You have analysed your code, found the problem, determined a solution. What is your question?

Comment: What makes you think that 10 is wrong and 11 is correct? "obviously" is not a good reason to think so. What is the definition of the designed (in contrast to the desired) return value? Maybe it is "position of the last character" instead of "length of the trimmed string".

Comment: @Yunnosch, my question is n should be 11, instead of 10, which is caused from s[n+1] = '\0'; but I would say s[n+1] is not quite right, s[++n] gave me the right answer, which means the code in the book is NOT quite right, did u see my meaning?

Comment: Find my answer to your most recent comment in my comment before it.

Comment: **Maybe it is "position of the last character" instead of "length of the trimmed string**, I totally understand, I would say the example best gives a note about what n refers to

Comment: Not sure whether I get your meaning. Did you realise that the book (the example) does not define the meaning of the return value, but should? If you consider my comment a satisfyinfg answer I will turn it into an official one. Otherwise (if you have satisfied yourself differently), you can create your own answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch, yes now I get it, the example does NOT define the meaning of return value, maybe I think about it too much, thx for pointing that

Comment: Btw, it's not listed as an errata here https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-errata.html

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over length and look ahead (behind?) one element to see if we need to trim it:

```
int trim(char s[]) {
    int n;
    for(n = strlen(s); n > 0; n--)
        if(s[n-1] != ' ' && s[n-1] != '\t' && s[n-1] != '\n')
            break;
    s[n] = '\0';
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that OP is asking for a way to trim and return length. They already know one. Not all question here are "How to code this?".

Comment: Op asked "how to deal with it?" so this would be one way.  But maybe you're right.  I will delete my answer if not helpful.

Comment: Do not act on my opinion, unless I convinced you to have the same one. The relevant opinion here is OPs. They might clarify if they want a different kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the book does not cleanly define the meaning of the return value.
But nearly:

> looking for the first character that is not ...

I think that returning 10 matches that, if it is to be considered the definition.
So the 10 actually seems to be the correct value to me, it is the position of the "first" (or "last") non-white space character before/from the end of the string.

To answer the question "How to deal with it?":
You might not actually care, if you only use the modified string and not the return value.
If you do use the return value you need to use it according to the definition (if you consider the quoted text to be the definition), i.e. in order to get the length you have to increment by one in the using/calling function (not in the called function).
Or you modify the function as you described. That option only exists if you "own" the code (which in your own project and tutorials you do...). Keep in mind however, that this option will usually NOT be available in professional context of larger projects. There the APIs and behaviour is defined elsewhere and cannot be changed locally.

I do by the way agree and feel with you (your implicit rejection of the probable definition) and at least one commenter. The return value definition "position of last non-white character" is not one which jumps to mind....

Comment: I think your answer perfectly valid (including the fact that it's the specification that matters & not my comment).  That said why would 'index of the last non-whitespace character' be a useful return value?  If it's not useful then it's a (specification) bug and not a feature.

Comment: @AllanWind I agree. But the code and its correctness is determined by the used definition - even if we both do not like it. ;-) If you have not encountered that very problem professionally yet you live in a better world (i.e. better suiting my wishes) than I do. Apart from that, a bug only exists if anybody uses the code differently than designed and gets caught by it acting as defined and not as desired.

Comment: Well, I see your meaning, that is what the for loop does, the for loop is going to find the first that is not...., and imagine that someone calls this function, I reckon they would expect 11 as result instead of 10, from a caller's perspective